# Get HTML CheckBox state in a WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

How can I get the state of a HTML CheckBox in a WebBrowser control?

I have the following variable in my class:

```
private WebBrowser quickStartGuideContentWebBrowser = new WebBrowser();
```

I also have the following constant in my class:

```
private const string doNotShowAgainCheckBoxElementId = "do-not-show-again-checkbox";
```

I also have the following function in my class;

```
private HtmlElement GetDoNotShowAgainCheckBox()
{
    HtmlDocument document = this.quickStartGuideContentWebBrowser.Document;
    if (document == null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("GetDoNotShowAgainCheckBox error: (document == null).");
        return null;
    }
    return document.GetElementById(doNotShowAgainCheckBoxElementId);
}
```

I am trying to implement a `IsDoNotShowAgainCheckBoxChecked` method as follows:

```
private bool IsDoNotShowAgainCheckBoxChecked()
{
    HtmlElement checkboxElement = GetDoNotShowAgainCheckBox();
    if (checkboxElement == null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("IsDoNotShowAgainCheckBoxChecked error: (checkboxElement == null).");
        return false;
    }
    // What magical incantation do I put here 
    // to retrieve the checked state of checkboxElement as a bool?
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to get the `checked` Attribute using the [HtmlElement.GetAttribute()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.getattribute) method.
It will be `"True"` or `"False"` (string), based on the state of the CheckBox.

```
if (quickStartGuideContentWebBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) return;

var chkBoxElm = quickStartGuideContentWebBrowser.Document.
    GetElementById(doNotShowAgainCheckBoxElementId);

if (chkBoxElm != null) {
    var state = chkBoxElm.GetAttribute("checked");
    if (state = "True") {
        Console.WriteLine("The CheckBox state is 'checked'");
    }
}
```

The `GetAttribute()` method can of course be used to retrieve any other Attribute of an [HtmlElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlelement), e.g., its `className`.